# how to make ssis map columns based order instead of column names

Tags: sql, ssis

I am working on a project where there are `700` columns in a remote server and our destination table have columns that starts with underscore for example if there is a `"SchoolName"` column in the remote server, on our destination table we would have `"_SchoolName"` or `"_School_Name"` column. We use to use DTS package to import data "which doesn't use column name to map, instead it uses the order of the column on the select statement to map the column in the destination table". Now we would like upgrading our DTS package to SSIS, but mapping `700` columns manually has been a nightmare. Is there any way we can map columns based  on the column orders instead of column name?

Comment: Facing a similar problem we usually query the source table with aliases in each column that match the destinations  table columns.

Comment: We have tried that, the remote server throws an error when there is an alias in the select query.

Comment: that's kind of weird. Could you post the query and rdbms version of that server?

Answer (score 0):

Aliases for each column should work .

If migration is state forward then Biml is a good option .

[Link](https://paultebraak.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/biml-xiii-building-extraction-etl-from-metadata-database-definitions/)